How can I prevent a component from reacting to model changes during an API fetch, allowing reactivity only after the fetch?
I'm working with a reactive frontend framework (VUE3), and I want my component to ignore model changes when fetching data from an API. However, once the fetch is complete, I need reactivity to respond to user-triggered changes only.
Is there a way to disable reactivity temporarily during the fetch and then re-enable it so that only changes made by the user are reactive? Any examples or best practices for achieving this would be very helpful.
minimal example
//main.component.vue
<template>
<input v-model="model.name" />
<childcomponent :name="model.name" />
</template>
<script setup>
import { onMounted, computed, ref } from "vue";

const model = ref({})

onMounted(async() => {
    const data = await fetch_data_from_api();
    model.value.name = data.name
})
</script>

//childcomponent.vue
<template>
{{data_computed}}
</template>
<script setup>
import { defineProps, defineEmits, watch, computed } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
    name: ''
})

const data_computed = computed(() => {
    //very very very complex problem
})
</script>

Is there a way within the Vue and reactivity paradigm, without resorting to hacks, to ensure that "data_computed" only executes when the user makes changes to the model?
vue3 avoid reactive change when api is fetching data when mounted

It sounds like you need to not use computed if automatic reactive changes is not desirable.  use regular ref and combine with methods and/or watch to update only when you need it to.
